# Cómo ordenar objetos comparándolos unos a otros en .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, backend, ordenamiento

Estoy intentando comparar dos objetos con 20 características cada uno de ellos. Se trata de saber si un User es lo más parecido posible a una Situation. He probado de momento con "OrderByDescending", pero no hay manera de conseguirlo. ¿Se debería de hacer con tuplas? ¿El planteamiento está equivocado?

Tengo esta clase preparada como "Helper" en mi proyecto. Su objetivo es listar elementos para que estén disponibles de cara a un sistema de paginación.

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

  namespace App.API.Helpers
 {
     public class PagedList<T> : List<T>
     {
         public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
         public int TotalPages { get; set; }
         public int PageSize { get; set; }
         public int TotalCount { get; set; }

          public PagedList(List<T> items, int count, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
         {
             TotalCount = count;
             PageSize = pageSize;
             CurrentPage = pageNumber;
             TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)pageSize);
             this.AddRange(items);
         }

          public static async Task<PagedList<T>> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, 
             int pageNumber, int pageSize)
         {
             var count = await source.CountAsync();
             var items = await source.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
             return new PagedList<T>(items, count, pageNumber, pageSize);
         }
     }
 }
```

También tenemos estos dos modelos: User

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace App.API.Models
{
    public class User : IdentityUser<int>
    {
        public string Funcion {get; set;}
        public int UserId {get; set;}
        public string Gender { get; set; }

        public int Item1 {get; set;} 
        public int Item2 {get; set;} 
        public int Item3 {get; set;} 
        public int Item4 {get; set;} 
        public int Item5 {get; set;} 
        public int Item6 {get; set;} 
        public int Item7 {get; set;} 
        public int Item8 {get; set;} 
        public int Item9 {get; set;} 
        public int Item10 {get; set;} 
        public int Item11 {get; set;} 
        public int Item12 {get; set;} 
        public int Item13 {get; set;} 
        public int Item14 {get; set;} 
        public int Item15 {get; set;} 
        public int Item16 {get; set;} 
        public int Item17 {get; set;} 
        public int Item18 {get; set;} 
        public int Item19 {get; set;} 
        public int Item20 {get; set;} 


        public virtual ICollection<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Like> Likers { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Like> Likees { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Message> MessagesSent { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Message> MessagesReceived { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
   
        public virtual ICollection<Familiar> Familiars {get; set;}
        public virtual ICollection<Situation> Situations {get; set;}
    }
}
```

Y una situación:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Amaz.API.Models
{
    public class Situation
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public int? item1 {get; set;}
        public int? item2 {get; set;}
        public int? item3 {get; set;}
        public int? item4 {get; set;}
        public int? item5 {get; set;}
        public int? item6 {get; set;}
        public int? item7 {get; set;}
        public int? item8 {get; set;}
        public int? item9 {get; set;}
        public int? item10 {get; set;}
        public int? item11 {get; set;}
        public int? item12 {get; set;}
        public int? item13 {get; set;}
        public int? item14 {get; set;}
        public int? item15 {get; set;}
        public int? item16 {get; set;}
        public int? item17 {get; set;}
        public int? item18 {get; set;}
        public int? item19 {get; set;}
        public int? item20 {get; set;}
    }
}
```

Mi objetivo es conseguir una comparación válida entre esos dos objetos. Cada situación requerirá al usuario que más se parezca en sus items a sus características. Hasta ahora he conseguido este método en el controlador.

```
public async Task<PagedList<User>> GetUsers(UserParams userParams)
{
    var users = _context.Users.OrderByDescending(u => u.LastActive).AsQueryable();

    users = users.Where(u => u.Id != userParams.UserId);

    users = users.Where(u => u.Gender == userParams.Gender);

    if (userParams.Likers)
    {
        var userLikers = await GetUserLikes(userParams.UserId, userParams.Likers);
        users = users.Where(u => userLikers.Contains(u.Id));
    }

    if (userParams.Likees)
    {
        var userLikees = await GetUserLikes(userParams.UserId, userParams.Likers);
        users = users.Where(u => userLikees.Contains(u.Id));
    }

    if (userParams.MinAge != 18 || userParams.MaxAge != 99)
    {
        var minDob = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-userParams.MaxAge - 1);
        var maxDob = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-userParams.MinAge);

        users = users.Where(u => u.DateOfBirth >= minDob && u.DateOfBirth <= maxDob);
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userParams.OrderBy))
    {
        switch (userParams.OrderBy)
        {
        case "Question1":
            users = users.OrderByDescending(u => u.Question1);
        break;
        case "Question2":
            users = users.OrderByDescending(u => u.Question2);
        break;
        case "Question3":
            users = users.OrderByDescending(u => u.Question3);
        break;
        case "Question4":
            users = users.OrderByDescending(u => u.Question4);
        break;
        case "Question5":
            users = users.OrderByDescending(u => u.Question5);
        break;
        case "Question6":
            users = users.OrderByDescending(u => u.Question6);
        break;
        case "Question7":
            users = users.OrderByDescending(u => u.Question7);
        break;
        case "Question8":
            users = users.OrderByDescending(u => u.Question8);
        break;
        case "Question9":
            users = users.OrderByDescending(u => u.Question9);
        break;
        case "Question10":
            users = users.OrderByDescending(u => u.Question10);
        break;
        case "Question11":
            users = users.OrderByDescending(u => u.Question11);
        break;
        case "Question12":
            users = users.OrderByDescending(u => u.Question12);
        break;
        case "Question13":
            users = users.OrderByDescending(u => u.Question13);
        break;
        case "Question14":
            users = users.OrderByDescending(u => u.Question14);
        break;
        case "Question15":
            users = users.OrderByDescending(u => u.Question15);
        break;
        case "Question16":
            users = users.OrderByDescending(u => u.Question16);
        break;
        case "Question17":
            users = users.OrderByDescending(u => u.Question17);
        break;
        case "Question18":
            users = users.OrderByDescending(u => u.Question18);
        break;
        case "Question19":
            users = users.OrderByDescending(u => u.Question19);
        break;
        case "Question20":
            users = users.OrderByDescending(u => u.Question20);
        break;
        //Añadido de casos
        case "created":
            users = users.OrderByDescending(u => u.Created);
        break;
        default:
            users = users.OrderByDescending(u => u.LastActive);
        break;
        }
    }

    return await PagedList<User>.CreateAsync(users, userParams.PageNumber, userParams.PageSize);
}
```

Por ejemplo, este código es capaz de ordenar a sus usuarios por la variable "Create" o "Last Active" y otras... Pero el siguiente paso, donde me encuentro atascado, es comparar a las situaciones con los usuarios. Cuando un usuario es más similar a una situación dada, debe ser colocado en primera posición en el array. ¿Pueden ayudarme?

Comment: Hablo sin ser experto.
Si que un `User` se similar a una `Situation` significa que el valor entero de cada uno de sus items sea idéntico o idénticos el mayor numero de estos. Podrías comprobar en una función el valor de estas propiedades para ambos objetos y establecer una *valor de similitud* ; 20/20:100% idénticos, 10/20:50% idénticos, etc.
Con dicho valor ya podrías ordenarnos en función de este. No se si es eso lo que pretendes.

Comment: Sí, sí. Es eso lo que pretendo. Pero...¿Qué función debo usar? Orderby? Sort?

Comment: Si ninguna te sirve, crea la tuya propia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no entendí tu planteamiento, pero puedes crear una variable temporal o un atributo temporal, donde evalúas cada característica y obtener un puntaje total, tanto en incidencias e incidencias en la misma posición

ejemplo:

```
persona 1, valores; y,n,n,n,n,y,y,n
persona 2, valores; n,n,y,n,n,y,y,y
```

donde  "y" = yes & "n" = no

```
 persona 1 = total y : 3
 persona 2 = total y : 4
```

esos valores los guardas como un atributo de "yes" totales, luego cada persona la comparas con las otras y estableces que si tienen  5 "yes" o más es compatible.
También puedes relacionar la posición

persona 1 = total "y" en misma posición con persona 2 : 2, pues en la posición 5 y 6 tienen la misma coincidencia.

Todo esto con un doble bucle for, donde cada 1 la comparas con todas las demás.